# Jquery loop post requests

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding jquery and javascript post request loop.

I am quite new to javascript, so i need help to creating a post loop.

I have this:
User input field: x@x.com;y@y.com (the user can specify emails divided by semicolon.

Right now i have this:

```
<button id="sendwebhook">Send</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sendwebhook').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      
url: "https://somesite.com/...",
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(
        {  "email":"x@x.com" }
      ),
      complete: function(){     alert("Success")        }
    });
  });
});
    
</script>
```

What i want to do is send a post request per email in the input field. So in this case i want to send this:

```
{  
"email":"x@x.com" 
},
{  
"email":"y@y.com" 
}
```

Or make two post requests with one json string. The user should be able to insert an unlimited amounth of emails, so i should be some kind of loop.

Comment: Just use the values with the semicolon separator

Comment: It would be much more performant to send across a single POST request with all the data and process it on the server. ie. send the `'x@x.com;y@y.com'` string once then `split(';')` on the server to get your array of values.

Comment: I see, but what i need help to is to create a "for each ;" loop, that generates the json string

Comment: To help you with that we need to see the HTML inputs where the user types the email addresses in to

Comment: It is just: ​<textarea id="txtArea" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>